# QGIS: where is the bilinear resampling option when saving to a new raster?

Tags: qgis, raster, image-pyramids

At 3.16.1, I am saving a raster using **Export > Save As**.  I would like to build pyramids for the output geotiff raster with *bilinear* resampling.  However, *bilinear* is not an option (see screenshot below). Unfortunately, [the documentation provides no guidance](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/gdal/rastermiscellaneous.html) about this.

Likewise, the **Build Overviews** tool does not have a *bilinear* option.

However, **Save As** and **Build Overviews** contain an *average* option, but again the documentation provides no explanation.  Is *average* the same as *bilinear*?  If not, how do I conduct *bilinear* resampling?

EDIT: *Bilinear* resampling is available elsewhere within QGIS, for example within the **Layer Styling** panel and the **Warp** tool.  Furthermore, the **Build Virtual Raster** tool contains both *bilinear* and *average* options(!?)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be a bug/missing feature in the QGIS menu. You can just write the file without overviews and run gdaladdo https://gdal.org/programs/gdaladdo.html from the command line.

> -r {nearest (default), average, rms, gauss, cubic, cubicspline, lanczos, average_magphase, mode}
>
> Select a resampling algorithm.
>
> nearest applies a nearest neighbour (simple sampling) resampler
>
> average computes the average of all non-NODATA contributing pixels.
> Starting with GDAL 3.1, this is a weighted average taking into account
> properly the weight of source pixels not contributing fully to the
> target pixel.
>
> rms computes the root mean squared / quadratic mean of all non-NODATA
> contributing pixels (GDAL >= 3.3)
>
> bilinear applies a bilinear convolution kernel.
>
> gauss applies a Gaussian kernel before computing the overview, which
> can lead to better results than simple averaging in e.g case of sharp
> edges with high contrast or noisy patterns. The advised level values
> should be 2, 4, 8, … so that a 3x3 resampling Gaussian kernel is
> selected.
>
> cubic applies a cubic convolution kernel.
>
> cubicspline applies a B-Spline convolution kernel.
>
> lanczos applies a Lanczos windowed sinc convolution kernel.
>
> average_magphase averages complex data in mag/phase space.
>
> mode selects the value which appears most often of all the sampled
> points.

Comment: Thanks for your answer; it makes sense.  I submitted it as a feature request: https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/40618